# Why does the requests library add extra headers to the ones I set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http-headers, python-requests

I am trying to do a post request on python utilizing the requests library, when I set my custom headers which are the following:

```
User-Agent: MBAM-C
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: True
Content-Length: 619
Connection: Close
```

However when It send the request with the custom headers it adds its own headers which give a bad request response from the server..

```
User-Agent: MBAM-C
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: Close
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: True
Content-Length: 559
```

Comment: None of those headers should cause a problem. The only curious thing is that the content length is different. It's presumably overriding what you gave because it doesn't match the actual post data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is due to the design goals of the requests project.

This behavior is documented [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers).  You may want to use a lower level library, if it is problematic for the library to be correcting content length or adding desirable headers.  Requests bills itself as: "an elegant and simple HTTP library for Python, built for human beings." and a part of that is advertising that it can accept compressed content and all mime types.

> Note: *Custom headers are given less precedence than more specific sources of information*. For instance:
>
> Authorization headers set with headers= will be overridden if credentials are specified in .netrc, which in turn will be overridden by the auth= parameter.
> Authorization headers will be removed if you get redirected off-host.
> Proxy-Authorization headers will be overridden by proxy credentials provided in the URL.
> *Content-Length headers will be overridden when we can determine the length of the content*.

Comment: Any recommendations for other libraries that I could use?